# Preparing iPhone App for Distribution in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

The iOS provision portal references are for a previous version of Xcode.  It doesn't look like they've updated it for version 4.2.  Does anyone know of a good step-by-step guide that is updated with the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a project:

1. Click menu Product > Archive
2. Open Window > Organizer > Archives
3. Select an archive
4. Click Validate ...
5. Click Distribute ...

Comment: Before doing this however, you have to create the app in itunes connect. You won't be able to distribute without first creating the app in itunes connect

Answer (score 0):

You will find some information regarding distribution in the [Xcode 4 user guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html), and in the [Tools Workflow Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html).

If you are wanting to distribute your app Ad-Hoc, [here](http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/) is a great guide that will explain how.